Replace the keys into different codes in JSON by JOLT
I have a JSON input as follows, need to replace the machine key with its name and then need to have following output JSON with the required mapping.
distance - "code" : "X2-P1"  
temp     - "code" : "X1-P1" 
weight   - "code" : "weight"

Need to change the values into string for some codes. Could someone help on this.
[
  [
    {
      "id": 26359,
      "name": "station green"
    },
    {
      "id": 22321,
      "name": "ravenstein"
    },
    {
      "id": 45328,
      "name": "workstation syn"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "time": "2024-06-16T21:30:40.289705Z",
      "machine": 22321,
      "temp": 18,
      "distance": 0.113,
      "long": 0.7866,
      "weight": 0.2563
    },
    {
      "time": "2024-06-16T19:02:16.970647Z",
      "machine": 26359,
      "temp": 27,
      "distance": 0.453,
      "site": 2219,
      "weight": 7.0261
    },
    {
      "time": "2024-06-17T19:32:13.180647Z",
      "machine": 26359,
      "temp": 56,
      "distance": 6.453,
      "site": 2219,
      "weight": 3.5463
    },
    {
      "time": "2024-32-16T19:02:16.970647Z",
      "machine": 78124,
      "temp": 22,
      "distance": 3.465,
      "site": 8723,
      "weight": 4.4312
    }
  ]
]

Output JSON
[
  {
    "stationname": "ravenstein",
    "Date": "2024-06-16T21:30:40",
    "data": [
      {
        "key": "X2-P1",
        "value": 0.113
      },
      {
        "key": "X1-P1",
        "value": 18
      },
      {
        "key": "weight",
        "value": 0.2563
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "stationname": "station green",
    "Date": "2024-06-16T19:02:16",
    "data": [
      {
        "key": "X2-P1",
        "value": 0.453
      },
      {
        "key": "X1-P1",
        "value": 27
      },
      {
        "key": "weight",
        "value": 7.0261
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "stationname": "station green",
    "Date": "2024-06-17T19:32:13",
    "data": [
      {
        "key": "X2-P1",
        "value": 6.453
      },
      {
        "key": "X1-P1",
        "value": 56
      },
      {
        "key": "weight",
        "value": 3.5463
      }
    ]
  }
]

If we do not have matching machine readings for a machine, then those machine details are not required to come to the output json. Same as that, if there is no matching machine details for a machine reading, then that machine readings are not required to come to out put json.

What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

yes, input json is different. It is not having the array called results.
{
"id": 22321,
"name": "ravenstein"
}
],
[
{
"time": "2024-06-16T21:30:40.289705Z",
"machine": 22321,
"temp": 18,
"distance": 0.113,
"long": 0.7866,
"weight": 0.2563
},

You can use the transformation below for this time :
[
  { //partition by id vs. machine attributes in order to match by their values
    //and reform objects with the keys of their matched values to accumulate the attributes
    //of common id and machine values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "name": "@1,id.station&", //reanme as desired this and the ones below
          "time": "@1,machine.Date",
          "distance": "@1,machine.data.X2-P1",
          "temp": "@1,machine.data.X1-P1",
          "weight": "@1,machine.data.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //match key vs. values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].&",
        "Date": {
          "*.*": {
            "$(0,1)": "[#4].&2" //extract the value the upto dot only, starting from the left 
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "*": {
            "$": "[#4].&2[#2].key",
            "@": "[#4].&2[#2].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

You seem to need matching "id" and "machine" values based on the last edit. In this case, you can alternatively use this one :
[
  { //determine fundamental pairs
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "machine|id": {
            "*": {
              "@1": "&1.match[]",
              "@2,name": "&1.stationname",
              "@2,time": "&1.&3.Date",
              "@2,distance": "&1.&3.data.X2-P1",
              "@2,temp": "&1.&3.data.X1-P1",
              "@2,weight": "&1.&3.data.weight"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //determine the length of the "match" arrays to
    //filter out the ones with single elements 
    //within the upcoming specs
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "match": "=size"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "match": { "": "" }, //get rid of this auxiliary attribute
        "*": {
          "@1,stationname": "@2,match.&1.stationname",
          "Date": {
            "*.*": {
              "$(0,1)": "@4,match.&3.&2" //extract the value the upto dot only, starting from the left 
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "*": {
              "$": "@4,match.&3.&2[#2].key",
              "@": "@4,match.&3.&2[#2].value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "stationname": { "": "" }, //get rid of this attribute
        "*": "[]"//get rid of the object keys while converting them to arrays
      },
      "1": {//except for match=1
        "": ""
      }
    }
  }
]


Thank you @Barbaros Özhan. This is working for above input json, but if there is any machine id, which is not having any machine readings then that machine details come to the output. Same as other way also, if there is any machine reading without machine details then machine reading comes to output json without machine details. I want to eliminate both cases. Could u please guide on that.
{
"id": 2333,
"name": "station red"
}
......................
{
"time": "2024-06-15T21:30:40.289705Z",
"machine": 22221,
................
"weight": 5.2563
}

Thanks @Barbaros Özhan for checking this. I modified the Input and Output JSONs, by including special cases.

Hi @Barbaros Özhan, could u please guide on getting additional scenarios.  I updated the input and output jsons. Thank you.

Hi @casper I've just added the new spec based on the new case.
